# PHP unserialize jQuery FORM post

Tags: php, jquery

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="form">
<input type="text" name="guest" id="guest_name" class="textbox"/><br />
<textarea name="textarea" id="text" class="textarea"></textarea/><br />
<input type="submit" id="submit" class="submit"/><br />
</form>
```

Jquery

```
$.post("events.php?action=send", { data :  $("#form").serialize() }, function(data, error) { }
```

***Tested if post DATA has the data in it:***

```
echo var_dump($_POST['data']);
```

**I get this:**

```
name=blabla&comment=blabla1
```

**And then when I do**

```
echo $_POST['guest'];
```

Nothing comes up, it's a **NULL.**

Question:

What have I done wrong? Why doesn't the POST guest get filled? if it's in DATA, and form's method is POST too.

Thanks!

Comment: It's because you are serializing the form in to the `data` field in your JQuery that you are getting it like that in PHP.  Try getting rid of the `data :` part in the post function so the data will be past to the `$_POST` array as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass the serialized string as the data parameter to $.post not an object whose data parameter is the serialized string

```
$.post("events.php?action=send", $("#form").serialize() , function(data, error) { }
```

Now you'll be able to access `$_POST['guest']` etc

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
parse_str($_POST['data'], $data);
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in the wrong way. Try like this

```
$.post(
        "events.php?action=send", 
        $("#form").serialize() , 
        function(data, error) {}
);
```

On php end access $_POST array like this

```
echo $_POST['guest'];
echo $_POST['textarea'];
```

Remove the data key you don't need it.`$("#form").serialize()` will make a query string in post which you can easily access as you get on usuall form submission.

References

[JQuery .serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Object literals must have key/value pairs. Line 3 of your code is not an improvement.

Comment: @Quentin before downvoting and commenting see the result. i am not going to remove my answers anyways because i have worked using like this for months.

Comment: what a shame the same thing posted by @Musa gets vote up and i get vote down without any reason.

Answer (score -1):

From what you've written it looks like $_POST['data']['guest'] would have what you're looking for in it.